# Trouble with getting value of field in SuiteScript2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have encoded string data to base64 format and setted the output to custom field  which is type is long text. In the user interface of the record I could see whole output of encoded value. But while try to get the output value with using rec.getText({fieldId:'customfieldname'}) somehow it breaks the value and doesn't return whole value. Is there any limit size of custom field value?

UserEvent script to get the custom field value:

```
function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {

  try {
      var invrecord = scriptContext.newRecord;
      var encodedata = invrecord.getText({fieldId: 'customfield'});

      log.debug({title:'Custom field value',
                details: encodedata});
      return true;
      }
  catch (e) {  
      log.error({
             title: e.name,
             details: e.message
               });
       return false;
     }}
   return {
   beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit, };});
```

To encode field value I have used code below:

```
        function encodeBase64Binary(strdata) {
        try{
            var base64EncodedString = encode.convert({
                string: strdata,
                inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8,
                outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64
            });
            return base64EncodedString;
        }
        catch (e) {
               log.error({
                   title: e.name,
                   details: e.message)} 
                  }
```

Comment: Long text holds 1,000,000 characters when created through the UI, 100,000 when created through SuiteScript. Have you tried `getValue` instead of `getText`?

Comment: You could also set it to HIDDEN + INLINEHTML since I doubt **seeing** base64 data is required

Comment: @ehcanadian yeah I have tried getValue. Both returns same result.

Comment: @niso How do you know the script is not getting the whole value? If you're relying on `log.debug` you may not see it all because logging truncates the value to 3,999 chars.

Comment: @ehcanadian  yeah exactly  it returns whole data but in logs it doesn't show all of them. In this case should I answer my  post or how could we close it?

Comment: If you could mark my answer as correct that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the field contains the value you're looking for, however, `log.debug` truncates the value to 3,999 characters. That's why you're not seeing the complete value.